# React Native - Undefined is not an object(evaluating 'item.menu_desc')

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to send some data to my database, but the data is also from my database. By pressing the send button the item/data that is displayed should be sent/added to the database.

I tried to use `this.setState({ name: item.menu_desc })` but it gave me this error:

[image: Error1]
Here's my code

```
export default class Dishes extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super (props)
        this.state = {
            ....
            ....
            name: null,
            menu_price: null,
        }
    }
    submit = ({ item, index }) => {
        this.setState({ name: item.menu_desc });          // my setStates
        this.setState({ menu_price: item.menu_price });
                fetch('http://192.168.***.***:3308/SendOrder/Send', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        ....
                        menu_desc: item.menu_desc,
                        menu_price: item.menu_price,
                    })
                }).then(res => res.json())
                    .then((responseJson) => {
                        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
                        console.log(responseJson);
                    })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
    }
        return (
            <View>
                .....
                <Text>Name: { item.menu_desc }</Text>       // This is name
                <Text>Price: ₱{ item.menu_price }</Text>    // This is price
                <Text>Status: { item.menu_status }</Text>
                .....
                <TouchableOpacity
                onPress = {(item,index) => this.submit(item,index)}>
                    <Text>Send Order</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
                <FlatList
                    data = {this.state.data}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    renderItem = {this._renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Error 2]

Answer (score 2):

you are calling `this.submit(item,index)`

where `item` is the first variable and `index` is the second variable.
But the submit function tries to destructure the item object like so.

`submit = ({ item, index }) => {`

remove the curly braces or send the arguments as an object.

Comment: it gives the same error sir, what about in my "menu_desc: item.name" and "menu_price: item.menu_price" ? do you think I'm doing this is right?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that `item` is undefined, therefore you can't call `.menu_desc` on it since it's not an object.

The inline function in `TouchableOpacity` should look like this: *(Notice how you don't actually need any argument in the anonymous inline function)*

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress = {
    () => {
      this.submit(item, index)
    }
  }
>
```

And since `submit()` takes in 2 arguments, you don't need the destructuring:

```
submit = (item, index) => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Close emulator
2. Kill all node.exe processes
3. remove all files in temp
4. remove node_modules
5. install babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types
6. npm install
7. react-native start --reset-cache
8. react-native run-android